# What's regexp `^\(.*\)\n\1$` mean?

Tags: regex, sed

I happen to find this regular expression in `sed` documents:

```
^\(.*\)\n\1$
```

And it explains:

```
 This matches a string consisting of two equal substrings separated
 by a newline.
```

I can see that it matches any characters, ends with a newline, but nothing more. Could someone give me an explanation?

Comment: Every ingredient is explained in this section: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns inside parentheses `()` are called *capture groups*.

The `\1` means "*whatever matched the first capture group*".

Here's a character by character breakdown:

```
 ^     -  matches the beginning of the input
 \(    -  begin capture group (the `(` character must be escaped with a backslash)
 .*    -  zero or more characters
 \)    -  end capture group
 \n    -  newline character
 \1    -  the text "captured" by the first capture group
 $     -  matches the end of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\1` part refers to the first parenthesized sub-expression, i. e. to the first "any characters" before the newline in your case.